# How to handle soap empty web method return on Symfony?

Tags: java, php, symfony, jax-ws

**Technologies**: JAX-WS and Symfony 4

**Problem**:

I coded a method to return me the posts based on their category from the database, the problem is when the result is empty **"When there are no posts on the passed category"** it throws an error on my website saying that return is undefined otherwise if it is not empty or a single value it works perfectly, any tips to avoid to face this problem when i deploy it with a fresh database with no posts on it.

**Java Code**:

```
/**
 * @param category
 * @param amountOfPosts
 * @return 
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "getPostsByCategory")
public ArrayList<Post> getPostsByCategory(
        @WebParam(name = "category") String category,
        @WebParam(name = "amountOfPosts") int amountOfPosts
) 
{
    ArrayList<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        this.connection = this.context.openConnection();

        String query = "SELECT * FROM POST WHERE POST_CATEGORY_ID = " + 
        category + " LIMIT " + amountOfPosts;
        new QueryRunner()
                .query(this.connection, query, new ArrayListHandler())
                .stream()
                .map(resultSet -> 
                {
                    Post post = new Post();
                    post.setPostId((int) resultSet[0]);
                    post.setPostTitle((String) resultSet[1]);
                    post.setPostDescription((String) resultSet[2]);
                    post.setPostCategoryId((int) resultSet[3]);
                    post.setPostContent((String) resultSet[4]);
                    post.setPostAuthor((String) resultSet[5]);
                    post.setPostDate((String) resultSet[6]);
                    post.setPostSlug((String) resultSet[7]);
                    post.setPostThumbnail((String) resultSet[8]);
                    post.setPostCountry((String) resultSet[9]);
                    post.setPostStateId((int) resultSet[10]);
                    return post;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> posts));

        this.context.closeConnection(this.connection);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AecaWebService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return posts;
}
```

**Symfony Code (PHP Code)**:

```
    $categoryOnePosts = $wsdl->getPostsByCategory(array(
        'category' => 1
        'amountOfPosts' => 5,
    ));

    return $this->render('view.twig', array(
        'categoryOnePosts' => $categoryOnePosts->return, #this causes the problem when empty
    ));
```

**Error in php**: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$return

Comment: why don't you just check if "return" property exists in $categoryOnePosts?

Comment: @DenisAlimov how do i check it if doesn't exists when 0?

Comment: property_exists($categoryOnePosts, 'return')